# Bootstrap working only on IIS Express

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple ASP.NET site under .NET 4.5 
In Visual Studio 2013 (IIS Express) it's working fine.
When I copy (not publish) it to another site, bootstrap is not working.
I have a menu, using "dropdown-toggle" class and it's not working there.
Under F12 tools from Chrome I see some js errors

> - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input --on  jquery
> - Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery -- on Bootstrap./js

Also when I shrink my browser to look like a cell phone, the menu is replaced by three lines but it's not expanding.
What I a missing here ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your path to the sources are not correct. Try to link to online sources like: [Bootstrap CDN Sources](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/).

To expand the menu you have to include JQuery.